# Why do all my decoded Strings have '?' at the end? Java String decoding

Tags: java, python, string, tweepy, decoding

I am retrieving tweets from Twitter using the Tweepy library (Python) and Kafka. The text is encoded in UTF-8 as this line shows:

```
self.producer.send('my-topic', data.encode('UTF-8'))
```

Where "data" is a String. Then, this data is stored into an Oracle NoSQL database in key-value format. For this reason, the tweet itself is encoded. I do this with Java:

```
Value myValue = Value.createValue(msg.value().getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

Finally, the tweets are retrieved by a Formatter developed in Java. In order to store it in a relational schema, I have to parse the tweet so I retrieve it as a String.

```
String data = new String(value.toByteArray(),StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

As you see, I maintain UTF-8 encoding in all the steps I make. However, when I see the text of the tweet in my database it's always cut. For example:

> RT @briIIohead: the hardest pill i had to swallow this year was learning that no matter how good you could be to somebody, no matter how mu?

Notice how it ends with '?' symbol, and it has been clearly cut. Well, this happens with every long tweet. I mean, if the text is like 30 characters long, then it shows fine, however anything longer than 100 or so is cut.

At first I thought it could be my table definition, but the field "Text" is declared as `VARCHAR2(400 CHAR)` which is the maximum number of characters a tweet can have in the social network.

Any ideas on how can I spot what's cutting the text and putting the '?' symbol at the end?

How "data" looks like:

```
{"created_at":"Tue May 28 09:23:36 +0000 2019","id":1133302792129351681,"id_str":"1133302792129351681","text":"RT @AppleEDU: Learn, create, and do more with iPad in your classroom. Get the free Everyone Can Create curriculum and bring projects to lif\u2026","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\/download\/iphone\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter for iPhone\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":1060510851889750022,"id_str":"1060510851889750022","name":"Rem.0112","screen_name":"0112Rem","location":"Mawson Lakes, Adelaide","url":null,"description":null,"translator_type":"none","protected":false,"verified":false,"followers_count":739,"friends_count":1853,"listed_count":10,"favourites_count":33406,"statuses_count":36936,"created_at":"Thu Nov 08 12:34:25 +0000 2018","utc_offset":null,"time_zone":null,"geo_enabled":true,"lang":null,"contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"F5F8FA","profile_background_image_url":"","profile_background_image_url_https":"","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_link_color":"1DA1F2","profile_sidebar_border_color":"C0DEED","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/1093157842163355649\/6oAdJTCs_normal.jpg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/1093157842163355649\/6oAdJTCs_normal.jpg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/1060510851889750022\/1546155144","default_profile":true,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"retweeted_status":{"created_at":"Thu May 23 15:15:16 +0000 2019","id":1131579354964725760,"id_str":"1131579354964725760","text":"Learn, create, and do more with iPad in your classroom. Get the free Everyone Can Create curriculum and bring proje\u2026 https:\/\/t.co\/aeeSPTXtFx","source":"\u003ca href=\"https:\/\/ads-api.twitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter Ads Composer\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":true,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":468741166,"id_str":"468741166","name":"Apple Education","screen_name":"AppleEDU","location":"Cupertino, CA","url":null,"description":"Spark new ideas, create more aha moments, and teach in ways you\u2019ve always imagined. Follow @AppleEDU for tips, updates, and inspiration.","translator_type":"none","protected":false,"verified":true,"followers_count":728781,"friends_count":273,"listed_count":2594,"favourites_count":13189,"statuses_count":2766,"created_at":"Thu Jan 19 21:26:14 +0000 2012","utc_offset":null,"time_zone":null,"geo_enabled":false,"lang":null,"contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"F0F0F0","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_link_color":"0088CC","profile_sidebar_border_color":"C0DEED","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":false,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/892429342046691328\/2SOlm_09_normal.jpg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/892429342046691328\/2SOlm_09_normal.jpg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/468741166\/1530123538","default_profile":false,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"is_quote_status":false,"extended_tweet":{"full_text":"Learn, create, and do more with iPad in your classroom. Get the free Everyone Can Create curriculum and bring projects to life through music, drawing, video and photography.","display_text_range":[0,173],"entities":{"hashtags":[],"urls":[],"user_mentions":[],"symbols":[]}},"quote_count":0,"reply_count":3,"retweet_count":3,"favorite_count":58,"entities":{"hashtags":[],"urls":[{"url":"https:\/\/t.co\/aeeSPTXtFx","expanded_url":"https:\/\/twitter.com\/i\/web\/status\/1131579354964725760","display_url":"twitter.com\/i\/web\/status\/1\u2026","indices":[117,140]}],"user_mentions":[],"symbols":[]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"scopes":{"followers":false},"filter_level":"low","lang":"en"},"is_quote_status":false,"quote_count":0,"reply_count":0,"retweet_count":0,"favorite_count":0,"entities":{"hashtags":[],"urls":[],"user_mentions":[{"screen_name":"AppleEDU","name":"Apple Education","id":468741166,"id_str":"468741166","indices":[3,12]}],"symbols":[]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"filter_level":"low","lang":"en","timestamp_ms":"1559035416048"}
```

I also must mention that this whole chunk is what's encoded. Then decoded, and finally parsed to be introduced in the database. All fields are correctly decoded and parsed, except "text" that's cut

Comment: How does `data` look like? What type is it? Can you somehow debug if the whole text is even available? E.g. are you somehow cutting the text or do you even receive the whole thing in the first place?

Comment: @Lino of course, I'll edit the question

Comment: I remember twitter upgrading their limit to 280 characters. Could it be that the library version you're using didn't adapt their internal limit? E.g. they still expect at max 140 characters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [official](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/counting-characters.html) documentation, a tweet has no more than "140" characters (that is a broad definition); but lately they changed it to `280`.

That same document says:

> Twitter counts the length of a Tweet using the Normalization Form C (NFC) version of the text.

So they first normalize the text (I'll let you figure out how this is done is java). And later they say:

> Twitter also counts the number of codepoints in the text rather than UTF-8 bytes.

Thus:

```
String test = "RT @briIIohead: the hardest pill i had to swallow this year was learning that no matter how good you could be to somebody, no matter how mu";
System.out.println(test.codePoints().count()); // 139
```

It seems that the initial tweet was 280 "characters" and your library that you use is not aware of that, so it only uses the previous 140 ones. Since that does some chunking, it seems that the chunking is wrong too it removes some "partial" bytes at the end. When you try to print those - java does not know what those (at the end) bytes actually mean (because of some wrong chunking) and simply says `?` (which is the default strategy on what to show when it simply does not understand something).

Comment: [List of issues](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+140) from the Tweepy Github page. Not entirely sure if it has been fixed, doesn't seem like it (all issues are either open or closed with no change)

Comment: @Lino cool! I only assumed the library was broken, you confirmed it! thank you

Comment: You're welcome, feel free to add that link into your answer to strengthen your claim :)